# how to deploy angular 2 app on shared host

Tags: angular

though there are quite a number of questions about this topic but none really answered it.

I have my angular 2 app, and I just want to deploy it to a shared host.

do I have to include or reference all my js files in the index.html

or

I should just copy my angular 2 folder completely and put in the shared host folder.

am a little confuse bout this, hope to shed light. thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack, you should have a script in your package.json for build the solution for Production, you can give a look to my angular-webpack-seed: https://github.com/kEpEx/angular2-webpack-seed

**package.json** (scripts)

```
"build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail",
```

**config/webpack/prod/js**

...

```
output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
  },
```

...

If you are using that, you just run `npm run build` and copy the `dist` folder to your shared hosting, that's it!